# Securing an on Premise non-SharePoint .NET WEBAPI method with o365 Authentication token

Tags: web-services, authentication, custom, security-token-service, token

We have a custom (non-sharepoint) .NET MVC WebAPI service running on premise.

At a high level, possible somehow to secure methods on that web service using o365/SharePoint Online Authentication tokens?

For example, we only want select SharePoint Online users to have access to a particular method on that Custom .NET Web Service.

Thanks.

Comment: You could add the users whom you you want to restrict access to in a group and check if the user is in the group in the web api using csom. Not sure why you want to use o365 tokens...

Comment: Calls to the service will be made from SharePoint Online pages behind the scenes.  We don't want users to have to authenticate more than once and when running these special pages.  When you say add users... what kind of users? these are o365 Cloud users.

Comment: Users wouldn't have to authenticate. Doesn't matter what kind of user. All I'm suggesting is to add those users whom you want to restrict to a group within SP. As you're running them from SP online pages, you could get the current user and in the web api, check whether he is in that group or not. If he is, exit from the method. If he isn't, execute the method for him.

Comment: yes I understand, but you would be passing this user information to the web service how? Plain text in a query string?  What's to stop a savvy user from seeing the formatted web service call and sharing it with anybody.